# Positioning floating span at the bottom of container

Tags: html, css

How do i position a Span at the bottom of it's container?

What i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wRbax/2/ 
I want `.box` to always be at the bottom of `.td`

**CSS**

```
.td {
    vertical-align: top;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.value {
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    background: blue;
    float: left;
}

.box {;
    padding: 2px;
    background: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="td">
            <span class="value">Value 1</span>
            <span class="box">X</span>
        </td>
        <td class="td">
            <span class="value">Value<br>2</span>
            <span class="box">X</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: will you please elaborate what you want ....

Comment: Use `.td {vertical-align: bottom;}` instead of top. Or do you mean that you want to do something else?

Comment: I want the span (the red box in the jsfiddle example) to always be in the bottom right corner of each table cell, no matter how big the cell ".td" or the box ".box" is...

Comment: @MyHeadHurts But then my values would be at the bottom of the cell aswell

Comment: @NikoM. I'm not sure you can easily achieve that. I think the most logical option would be to put the span elements in different cells: http://jsfiddle.net/wRbax/18/

Comment: @MyHeadHurts That is exactly what i want it to look like. Sadly i would have to change lots of things in my project code to achieve that by extending the table. But if there is no other solution this one has to do it i guess. Thanks alot for trying

Answer (score 0):

see this working example

http://jsfiddle.net/wRbax/19/

replace span with div

Comment: As you can see in your example ".box" is still not at the bottom of its container. And the obvious reason i used span instead of div is because i want those 2 blocks next to each other.

Comment: @NikoM. check my updated solution once, let me know is it correct or need some more changes

Comment: Well the 2 blocks are still not next to each other and ".box" is not at the bottom of its container :/
http://jsfiddle.net/wRbax/20/ would be the right way how it should look like, but it seems it is not possible without using fixed values :'(
Thanks alot for trying, but i guess i will go for javascript for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add the following rule to your box class in the html:-

display: block;

http://jsfiddle.net/LMgRa/

But as mentioned earlier you'd achieve the same by using a div instead.
Matt

Update: try this instead:-
http://jsfiddle.net/LMgRa/1/

Comment: Is there no way using span? By doing this my blocks are not next to each other anymore and .box is still not at the bottom of it's container :'(

Comment: I think your html might be a bit wonky.  Does this look any better?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wRbax/20/ is the way i want it to look like. Just without the absolute positioning, so there is no fixed margin on ".value" and ".box" can as big as it wants to be. But it seems this is not possible. Thanks for the help though :)